# Laravel. DDD(domain-driven design) interaction between layers. Where to create an entity object and how to save it?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I have a Product entity. Is it correct to create an entity in the controller(and so and)
how to create entity object correctly and save?
how to interact with entities, on which layer?

```
$product = new Product('Test', 123);
$productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

In DDD approach, normally you will have an application service layer that executes a concrete use case of your application.

In that application service you can instantiate the entity and persist it, for example.

That application service should be used by your controller, not your entities.

Comment: I have Entity Product.
if I get you right, i Need service, how example: CreateProductService, where i need create new Product and passed in to Repository. Inside of service:
$product = new Product('Test', 123);
$productRepository->save($product);